# How to figure out which files impact the incubator-netbeans build?

Tags: java, netbeans, build, ant

I'm experiencing the following `ant` build failure for the [`incubator-netbeans`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans) project:

```
> git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans
Cloning into 'incubator-netbeans'...
remote: Counting objects: 161480, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: Total 161480 (delta 45), reused 103 (delta 30), pack-reused 161321
Receiving objects: 100% (161480/161480), 126.01 MiB | 5.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (82375/82375), done.
Checking out files: 100% (44314/44314), done.
> cd incubator-netbeans/
> ant
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Buildfile: /tmp/incubator-netbeans/build.xml

-jdk-pre-preinit:

-jdk-preinit:

-jdk-warn:

-jdk-presetdef-basic:

-jdk-default:

-jdk-init:

-load-build-properties:

bootstrap:
[mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/incubator-netbeans/nbbuild/build/antclasses
[javac] Compiling 4 source files to /tmp/incubator-netbeans/nbbuild/build/antclasses
[downloadbinaries] Creating /tmp/incubator-netbeans/javahelp/external/jhall-2.0_05.jar

BUILD FAILED
/tmp/incubator-netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:72: File /tmp/incubator-netbeans/javahelp/external/jhall-2.0_05.jar requested by /tmp/incubator-netbeans/javahelp/external/binaries-list to have hash CA70822C47A67FC3A11670270567C2D01566DAE1 actually had hash DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709

Total time: 1 second
```

which I reported at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-787. It doesn't attract attention because I can't reproduce it on any CI service, inside Ubuntu Docker images or inside VirtualBox images, really only on my Ubuntu 18.04 (the issue thus should have a low priority and I'm assuming that the devs checking the issue tracker are handling it as such, therefore I thought, I might find a way to reproduce it myself).

Since deletion of the source root and a new clone doesn't fix the problem, I need to figure out a way to find the file (I assume only a configuration file outside the source root can be the cause) which causes the failure. The might be other reasons I can't think of. I can't remember whether I ever set something up outside the source root or not.

I might wait for the build system to be migrated to Maven (how many decades has this idea been floating around?), but I consider it not a valid workaround for this particular question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `ant` build system or a tool it uses under the hood isn't capable of downloading erroneous files which are stored in `~/.hgexternalcache`, but simply fails instead without any useful feedback. The issue can thus be fixed by deleting the cache directory.

The issue has been updated with a link to this answer and marked solved.